# Amazon Linux上のMySQLでnull:falseが効かない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, amazon-linux

サーバー構築初心者でEC2上にAmazon Linuxを立てています。

全く同じ手順で1からrailsプロジェクトを作成し、`null:false` を付けるとmac上では保存できない一方、Amazon Linux上だとMySQLは空で保存出来てしまいます。

どのようなことが考えられるでしょうか？

情報を書き過ぎると複雑になってしまうと考えたので、必要最低限で記載しました。
足りない部分があれば、メッセージいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 保存した後のデータをコンソールから確認してみると

nil?  →  false
empty? → true
blank? → true
となりました。

つまり、centosの場合(現在のMySQLの設置上)、空のデータは保存できるけれども、
nilは保存できない
といった形になっていそうです。

Comment: MySQL上では対象のフィールドについてNullは許可していますか？またフィールドのデフォルトの値は何を設定していますか？またDBに保存の際にMySQLでワーニングは発生していませんか？